# Problem with autoreconf

Tags: autoconf

I'm having a problem when trying to build the library `libmatheval` (problem is reoccurring regardless of version chosen).
The documentation says that before building and installing it I should run `autoreconf -fi`, which is causing an issue.

The terminal is giving me this:

```
configure:11759: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS_FROM_LIBS
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/local/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

As far as I can tell this is a problem connected to guile. There is some information about this (or a similar) problem here: 
https://sourceforge.net/p/autogen/mailman/message/29764332/ with the main comment being;

```
AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS_FROM_LIBS is defined in gnulib/m4/lib-link.m4 and needs  the file gnulib/build-aux/config.rpath. 

In other words, using guile.m4 requires using gnulib.
```

Though I am not sure exactly what this means my uneducated guess is that autoconf is looking in the wrong place for guile? I've tried adding some directories to LD_LIBRARY_PATH but sadly it has not worked. GNUlib is installed an up to date.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 
GNU Autoconf is on version 2.64

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to build it from source? [libmatheval-dev 1.1.11](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libmatheval-dev) appears to be available from the repository - there doesn't appear to be a more recent version

Comment: Also, what documentation exactly is telling you that you need to run autoreconf? It's rarely necessary when building GNU software on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the edit George. Ah I was not aware it was available from the repository; I will try installing it from there a go - thanks.

Comment: You will need to [enable the universe repository](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) if you have not already done so.